# Decreasing a float after a set amount of time

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is a little difficult to explain but I want to write a piece of code that decreases the users oxygen level after a set amount of time. For example, if the user is swimming then the users oxygen level should go down .5 every 5 seconds. I have the general idea but I can not seem to figure out how to write the code. Here is what I have thus far

**C#**

```
    public float timer = 60;
    public float oxygen = 100;
    public float decreaseOxygen = 0.5f;
    public float oxygenDecreaseInterval = 2;

    private float decreaseOxyOverTime(float amountToDecrease)
    {
        oxygen = oxygen - amountToDecrease;
        return oxygen;
    }

     private float createDelayTimer()
    {
        float delayedTime = timer - oxygenDecreaseInterval;
        InvokeRepeating("delayedTime", 0, 5f);

        return delayedTime;
    }

void Update()
{

        if (timer >= createDelayTimer())
        {
            oxText.text = "Oxygen: " + decreaseOxyOverTime(decreaseOxygen) + "%";
        }

        timer -= Time.deltaTime;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, @Andrew was the closest to the answer but this is what I was looking for:

**C#**

```
public float timer = 60;
public float oxygen = 100;
public float decreaseOxygen = 0.5f;
public float oxygenDecreaseInterval = 2;

private float compareTime = 0.0f;

private float decreaseOxyOverTime(float amountToDecrease)
{
    oxygen = oxygen - amountToDecrease;
    return oxygen;
}
void Update()
{
    compareTime += Time.deltaTime;

    timeText.text = "Time Remaining: " + timer;
    oxText.text = "Oxygen: " + oxygen + "%";

    if (compareTime >= oxygenDecreaseInterval)
    {
        compareTime = 0f;
        oxText.text = "Oxygen: " + decreaseOxyOverTime(decreaseOxygen) + "%";
    }

    timer -= Time.deltaTime;

}
```

Comment: On mine i got rid of the `deltaTime` call every frame it would be a bit more economical with just a cached start time and current time comparison

Comment: instead of `comapreTime` since you already have `timer` just do `if (Mathf.Approximately(timer % oxygenDecreaseInterval, 0f))` and you can get rid of the `compareTime` variable altogether

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a `Coroutine`?

When you want to start the decrease in oxygen you can do something like this:

```
StartCoroutine("DecreaseOverTime", amountToDecreaseBy, interval);

IEnumerator DecreaseOverTime(float amountToDecreaseBy, float interval)
{
  float adjust = 0;
  while(true)
  {
   var prev = DateTime.Now;

   yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval-adjust);

   adjust = DateTime.Now.Subtract( prev ).Seconds - interval;
  }
}
```

I'm assuming that `interval` is measured in seconds.

Note: I'm calling `StartCoroutine` by using it's name instead of just calling the method so you can stop it later with `StopCoroutine`.

Comment: Why do u have `while(true)` ?

Comment: do run the coroutine until you stop it. otherwise it would just run once

Comment: This seems to be programmed in JavaScript.

Comment: It is not javascript. It's C#

Comment: Oh, wait is this psuedocode then? Because C# does not contain a "var" keyword.

Comment: Yes it does. It infers the type of the variable based on its usage

Answer (score 1):

```
float holdingBreath = -1f;
float delay = 5.0f;
float oxyLevel = 5.0f;
float rate = 0.5f;

void HoldBreathToggle()
{
    holdingBreath = holdingBreath > 0f ? -1f : Time.time;
}

void Update()
{
    if(holdingBreath > 0f)
    {
        if(Mathf.Approximately((Time.time - holdingBreath) % delay, 0f))
            oxyLevel -= rate;
    }
}
```

now all you have to do is mess with rate till you have it at a good speed.

Comment: This is similiar to what I am looking for but here is the issue. The time is going to be dynamic so let's say for example every 5 seconds the user will lose .5 hp does that make sense?

Comment: I changed it a bit try it now